# Enlazar 'this' de dos contextos distintos

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, prototipos

Estoy creando un prototipo con sus event listeners y sus respectivos handlers.

El tema es que necesito dos 'this' en un mismo handler:

```
this._items = $(".playlist-item");
//...
this._items.click( this.itemClickedHandler( ?? ) );
```

En otros handlers donde sólo necesitaba el this de la instancia utilizaba el método bind:

```
this._player.on('ended', this.videoEndedHandler.bind(this))
```

De momento he dejado el código, para que al menos funcionase, de este modo:

```
var that = this;
this._items.click(function(){
   var index = $(this).data("slick-index");
   that.jumpTo(index);
});
```

Comment: ¿Quieres tener dentro de un callback dos contextos? Es decir, el contexto del objeto que llama a la función y el contexto superior. En ese caso, no tienes más remedio que guardar el contexto superior en una variable como haces en el último código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El tema es que necesito dos 'this' en un mismo handler:

No puedes, hay una sola variable y no puede tener dos valores al mismo tiempo :/
Y no tiene sentido que lo hagas así ya que si `this` fuera *este y aquel* al mismo tiempo ¿como luego sabe el compilador a cual te refieres? Ademas si pudieras usar `this` de esta forma creo que seria de bastante confuso de leer el programa.

El enfoque actual es correcto, pero creo que la variable `that` debería llamarse de otra forma para que **explicitamente** se entienda de que pieza se trata. Por ejemplo: `var moduloPadre` (ok, no es tan buen ejemplo)

Nota anegdotica: es posible hacer un mix de ambos objetos y bindearlo, pero eso seria aun peor de leer y mas difícil de mantener y claro, no puede haber 2 miembros con el mismo nombre pues uno pisaría al otro, ej:

```js
var este = { var1: 'valor1', var2: 'valor2' }; 
var aquel = { var2: 'valor3', var3: 'valor4' };

// haces la mezcla de objetos
var mezcla = Object.assign(este, aquel);

// preparas la funcion bindeada a la mezcla
var bindeada = function() {
   console.log( this );
}.bind( mezcla );

// esta la invocaria el callback 
bindeada();
```

Comment: Exactamente. sabía que no podían ser dos 'this' distintos y a la vez, no me expliqué del todo bien. Quería saber si había una forma mas 'limpia' de escribir el código que ya tenía. ¡Gracias!

Comment: La convención es usar  `_this`. Al menos, esa es la convención que propone ESLint.